# lstrip is removing a character I wouldn't expect it to

Tags: python

The following code:

```
s = "www.wired.com"
print s
s = s.lstrip('www.')
print s
```

outputs:

```
www.wired.com
ired.com
```

Note the missing `w` on the second line. I'm not sure I understand the behavior. I would expect:

```
www.wired.com
wired.com
```

EDIT:

Following the first two answers, I now understand the behavior. My question is now: **how do I strip the leading `www.` without touching the rest**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to `string.lstrip` is a list of characters:

```
>>> help(string.lstrip)
Help on function lstrip in module string:

lstrip(s, chars=None)
    lstrip(s [,chars]) -> string

    Return a copy of the string s with leading whitespace removed.
    If chars is given and not None, remove characters in chars instead.

>>>
```

**It removes ALL occurrences of those leading characters.**

```
print s.lstrip('w.')  # does the same!
```

**[EDIT]:**

If you wanted to strop the initial `www.`, but only if it started with that, you could use a regular expression or something like:

```
s = s[4:] if s.startswith('www.') else s
```

Comment: +1 I understand it now. How would you go around removing just the leading 'www.' then ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation:

> The chars argument is a string specifying the **set** of characters to be removed...The chars argument is not a **prefix**; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped

You would achieve the same result by just saying:

> 'www.wired.com'.lstrip('w.')

If you wanted something more general, I would do something like this:

```
i = find(s, 'www.')
if i >= 0:
   s = s[0:i] + s[i+4:]
```

Comment: 1. You may want to show the import statement that `find` came from, and 2. this will remove it from the middle of the string.  `string.replace` would work better for replacing/removing an arbitrary occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the leading `www.`

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "www.wired.com"
>>> re.sub(r'^www\.', '', s)
'wired.com'
```